# How do I link Extensions to Project (Visual Studio C++ )

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, nuget

I just installed the following library 
https://github.com/scottdensmore/callisto/tree/cpp
via NuGet and via the Extensions and Updates Manaer in C++.

But how can I link the library to my Project.

using Callisto.Controls; gives me Callisto is not defined

Thx for the help in advance

Edit: I tried #pragma comment( lib, "Callisto" ) and #pragma comment( lib, "callisto" ) but its not working.
I also don't know the exact name bc its installed as an extensions directly via visual studio and/or via NuGet

Answer (score 0):

To link with a lib file, place a line like this in your source file:

```
#pragma comment( lib, "name_of_lib_file" )
```

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0aews7.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

At your project workspace, try go to *workspace manager* (It is something like that), you will see below `projects` the folders like: `Source`, `Resources`, `Headers`. Now, right click to `Resources` folder then add something like `Add dependency` (I forgot it already since I switch to Code::Blocks) then locate the `.lib` file of your library.